# I have a setTimeout function, how to use cleartimeout function to stop this loop

Tags: jquery, settimeout, cleartimeout

I have a setTimeout function just like below.

```
setTimeout(function(){gameEngine(radioValue,height,width,gameLevel)}, 1500);
```

I have used the following clearTimeout format and thats not working. What is wrong here?

```
clearTimeout(gameEngine(radioValue,height,width,gameLevel));
```

Comment: setTimeout returns an id to a process, so save that id in a variable and then clear it with clearTimeout

Answer (score 0):

`setTimeout` function returns an ID that you can pass on to `clearTimeout` function to stop your timer.

```
let gameTimer = setTimeout(function(){...}, 1500);
```

Now whenever you want to stop your timer, call `clearTimeOut` method and pass it your timer ID.

```
clearTimeout(gameTimer);
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to store `setTimeOut` function in a variable(ex. x)
When you want to `cleartimeout` you call is with a parameter x.
for example:

```js
var timeoutID;

function delayedAlert() {
  timeoutID = window.setTimeout(slowAlert, 10000);
}

function slowAlert() {
  alert("That was really slow!");
}

function clearAlert() {
  window.clearTimeout(timeoutID);
}
```

```html
<p>Live Example</p>
<button onclick="delayedAlert();">Show an alert box after 10 seconds</button>
<p></p>
<button onclick="clearAlert();">Cancel alert before it happens</button>
```

in your case:

```js
var x=setTimeout(function(){gameEngine(radioValue,height,width,gameLevel)}, 1500);

clearTimeout(x);
```